# HttpPostedFileBase always null when using a custom Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I created an HTML helper for file (File and FileFor) as follows:

```
public static IHtmlString File(this HtmlHelper html, String text, String name, IDictionary<String, Object> attributes)
{
    // Code snip
    TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
    input.MergeAttribute("type", "file");
    input.MergeAttribute("name", name, true);
    input.GenerateId(name);

    return // ...
}

public static IHtmlString FileFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, String text)
    where TModel : class
{
    return FileFor(html, expression, text, null);
}
```

Everything works fine unless I have the following model:

```
public class AdvertViewNewModel : ViewModel
{
    public AdvertModel Advert { get; set; }

    public class AdvertModel
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in this case ASP.NET renders the input as:

```
<input type="file" name="Advert.Image" id="Advert_Image">
```

And my Html Helper renders it as:

```
<input type="file" name="Image" id="Image">
```

Which would be ok if I would not have a child class.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

My FileFor code:

```
public static IHtmlString FileFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, String text, IDictionary<String, Object> attributes) where TModel : class {

  ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

  String field = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

  String name = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(field);

  return File(html, text, metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? field, attributes == null ? new RouteValueDictionary() : attributes);

}
```

Comment: Please post how `FileFor` reads the name from the `expression`

Comment: Yes, I just updated to include that code. Basically I am using: String name = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(field);

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? field
```

To

```
metadata.PropertyName
```

I think it is picking up the DisplayName instead of the PropertyName.